# how to collect hadoop tasktracker status?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to collect various metrics for active tasttrackers but it throws an exception

Not sure why?

```
for(String s: jc.getClusterStatus(true).getActiveTrackerNames()){
            System.out.println("tt "+s);
            System.out.println(""+ new org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.server.jobtracker.TaskTracker(s).getAvailableSlots(TaskType.MAP)); }
```

## output

prompt $ /installs/hadoop-0.20.2//bin/hadoop jar tools.jar tools.MetaInfo

tt tracker_10.0.0.6:localhost/127.0.0.1:53256 java.lang.NullPointerException     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.server.jobtracker.TaskTracker.getAvailableSlots(TaskTracker.java:90)     at tools.MetaInfo.(MetaInfo.java:44)     at tools.MetaInfo.main(MetaInfo.java:51)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:186) jabir:CompareHdfs jabir.ahmed$

Not sure why it doesnt display the available slots but displays an error

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to collect various metrics for active tasttrackers but it throws an exception

`new TaskTracker()` will create a new TaskTracker which is not you wanted to do.

Check the [JobCounter](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobCounter.java) and the [TaskCounter](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskCounter.java) classes for the various built-in counters in the Hadoop framework. This [tutorial](http://philippeadjiman.com/blog/2010/01/07/hadoop-tutorial-series-issue-3-counters-in-action/) will help to retrieve counters. Besides the in-built counters, [custom counters](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#metrics) can also be built for any application specific data for any additional data related to the Hadoop framework.

Also, split the lines into multiple lines. With a().b().c().d().e(), it's very difficult to know when the NPE came from.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find current status, what are thing doing with tasktracker
http://x.x.x.x:50060/tasktracker.jsp